# Dynamically registering and removing beans in spring and monitoring through Visual VM

Tags: spring, spring-boot, visualvm

I am working on a small POC/API for **dynamic bean creation and removal** as per user request. I am monitoring the creation and removal through **Visual VM** on my local machine.

**For Dynamic Bean Creation:**

> Controller Class snippet:

```
@Autowired
DBCDemoService service;
@Autowired
DefaultListableBeanFactory ctx;

@GetMapping(value = "/register-bean")
public ResponseEntity<Object> registerBean(@RequestParam String beanName, @RequestParam String clusterHost, @RequestParam String clusterPort) {

        service.registerDynaCluster(clusterHost, clusterPort, beanName);
        //Cluster cluster = (Cluster) ctx.getBean(bean);

        LOGGER.info(cluster.toString());
        LOGGER.info("Connection status: " + cluster.connect()); //Mock connect
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

> Service Class Snippet

```
@Autowired
DefaultListableBeanFactory context;

public void registerDynaCluster(String host, String port, String beanName) {
    GenericBeanDefinition gbd = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    gbd.setBeanClass(Cluster.class);

    MutablePropertyValues mpv = new MutablePropertyValues();
    mpv.add("host", host);
    mpv.add("port", port);
    
    gbd.setPropertyValues(mpv);

    context.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, gbd);

}
```

**For Bean Removal:**

> Controller Class snippet:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/de-register-bean")
public ResponseEntity<Object> deRegisterBean(@RequestParam String beanName) {

        if (ctx instanceof BeanDefinitionRegistry)
            ((BeanDefinitionRegistry) ctx).removeBeanDefinition(beanName); 
        /*
         * if (ctx instanceof BeanDefinitionRegistry) ctx.destroySingleton(beanName);
         * 
         * return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
         */
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now, When I hit the /register-bean end-point with the necessary params, the beans are getting created successfully. But when I hit the **/de-register-bean** end-point (with the already created bean name) and monitor it in **Visual VM**, the "Live Objects" count for the corrresponding class doesn't decrease immediately (maybe after a long wait, it will).
Where am I going wrong? Or, is there a way for destroying the bean immediately after calling the removeBeanDefinition() and verify the same in the Visual VM console?
[image]

Comment: Removing it from the definition from the context doesn't mean the bean instance is removed? Next to that, even if the instance is removed from the context it doesn't mean it is garbage collected directly (it still could even be in-use/referenced somewhere else).